# Excel RoundUp with IF statement not working.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to capture items that are > 80% to multiply by 3, IF not, to multiply by the percentage given, then round up[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTLLl.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTLLl.png). However, I'm receiving a message that I have too few arguments for this function.

=ROUNDUP(IF(H2>.79,G2*3*H2,IF(H2<.8,G2*3*H2,0)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RoundUP() requires two  arguments.  The second sets the place to which to round.

```
=ROUNDUP(IF(H2>.79,G2*3*H2,IF(H2<.8,G2*3*H2,0)),2)
```

This will round up to the hundredth place.  The 2 is the significant diggits in the decimal.  To do it to the Tens it would be -1. To the integer 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `roundup` requires two pieces:

- a number to round
- a number of decimal places to round to

You have only provided the first. By adding the `bolded` bit in the formula below (with whatever level of specificity you choose) it will run properly:

```
=ROUNDUP(IF(H2>0.79,G2*3*H2,IF(H2<0.8,G2*3*H2,0))**,0**)
```